# iOS: Unable to register for notification after calling unregister notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I am calling the following method to unregister push notifications.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

However, if I try to register for remote notifications again with the following code, it doesn't seem to work.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

According to some StackOverflow posts, some said I shouldn't unregister push notifications this way because it isn't reliable. I thought I would be able to register for notification again, but it seems that I can't. Is this normal?